# RPC with Angular-Wakanda

Tags: wakanda

How do I call a method in module declared as rpc module server side at client side with angular-wakanda? I installed angular-json-rpc but I don't know what is the correct url for the module. I always receive an error "not found".

Answer (score 0):

The correct Url for the RPC module is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/rpc-proxy/rpcName"></script>
```

But it doesn't work with angularJs, it work only with the WAF framework(prototype).
I suggest you to use entity methods or dataclass methods to communicate with the server.
Walid.

Comment: Because the fact that you have to grant "describe" rights for the appropriate dataclass I am looking for another way to execute server side code. Using a dummy class could be a workaround.

Comment: you can use request handlers : http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/HTTP-Request-Handlers/Introduction-to-HTTP-Request-Handlers.200-803294.en.html